# AdMob disabled ads due to a Google Play policy violation

Tags: android, google-play, admob, privacy-policy

I have a problem. One month ago my app was removed from Google play because i didn't have a privacy policy link inside the app and in the app's Google Play page. After i fixed the issue, my app went back online. When Google Play removed the app, AdMob has automatically stopped serving ads to my app and notified me via e-mail. The e-mail says that if Google Play restores the app (is actually online on the store since 3 days), i can send an Appeal by clicking the link in the email. Well, after i compile the appeal form and submit, i receive always the same automatic email reply from admob:

GOOGLE PLAY REMOVAL: AdMob publishers are not permitted to abuse or promote the abuse of any Google product, such as Google Play, YouTube, or Blogger. This includes circumventing, or providing the means to circumvent, the policies or terms of these or other Google products, such as by allowing users to download YouTube videos.

If your app is removed by Google Play policy enforcement, please contact Google Play about an app removal here. If Google Play reinstates your app, please submit an appeal to our team.

I don't know what to do, I would appreciate useful information from people who have had the same problem and have solved it

Comment: Did you check for any violation ? Any abusive words about Google products ?